# More Simplified query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE City LIKE 'a%'
Union
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'e%'
Union
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'i%'
Union
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'o%'
Union
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'u%';
```

Answer (score 6):

You would use `regexp`:

```
select distinct city
from station
where city regexp '^[aeiou]';
```

Comment: This is Great!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OR` for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE City LIKE 'a%' OR City LIKE 'e%' OR City LIKE 'i%' OR City LIKE 'o%' OR City LIKE 'u%';
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL where clauses can have [multiple conditions](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-and-or-not):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city LIKE 'a%'
OR city LIKE 'e%'
OR city LIKE 'i%'
OR city LIKE 'o%'
OR city LIKE 'u%';
```

Further, since you only care about starts with, you can switch to a [substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE substr(city,1,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Although note if `city` has an index on it this may be less performant (requiring a full table scan)

Answer (score 0):

We can use multiple OR(s) in where conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
    FROM STATION
    WHERE CITY LIKE 'u%'
      OR CITY LIKE 'e%'
      OR CITY LIKE 'a%'
      OR CITY LIKE 'i%'
      OR CITY LIKE 'o%';
```